# IK rig bending incorrectly

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

Specifically, the knees seem to be bending... Inwards? This is a basic, custom IK rig, based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYgznqvbisM&t=2684s) tutorial from Ryan King Art. You can see the issue below. Blend file is there too.

[image: Fig. 1]
[image: Fig. 2]
[image: Fig. 3]
[image: Fig. 4]

[image]

Comment: If you move the IK pole forwards further than the knee, does the knee still bend to the side?

Comment: hello please share the file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati Afraid so. And adjusting the pole angle just makes the feet point the wrong way, or - in the best case scenario - make the leg bend in the correct direction, but wrong angle.

Comment: @moonboots Done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bend the knees a bit in *Edit* mode so that it knows how to bend it in *Pose* mode:

[image]

Also straighten the legs:

[image]

Comment: Damn it, I should've known. As an aside, is there seriously no way to directly edit joints in blender?

Comment: What do you mean by edit joints?

Comment: Like just locking the joint along an axis. I don't know how much good it would do me after export, but still.